# JQuery -> How can I find a div with specific id then addClass('activeFeaturedNews');

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.btnReadMore').click(function(){
   var tempId = $(this).attr('id');
   $('div#'+tempId).addClass('activeFeaturedNews');
});
```

From the first page, When I click on an anchor tag it will pass its Id to the next page then find the div with the same id then add class.

Comment: _pass it;s Id to the next page_ How you are doing it?

Comment: as you have unique id, instead of `$('div#'+tempId)` just try `$('#'+tempId)`

Comment: $('div#'+tempId).addClass('activeFeaturedNews'); this will do what you need, just think how you are going to pass this tempid to next page

Answer (score 1):

On click of the anchor tag you can keep the id in the `localStorage` and on next page use `getItem` interface to get the stored element

```
$('.btnReadMore').click(function(){
   localStorage.setTime("tempId",$(this).attr('id');
})
```

On next page

```
var getItemId = localStorage.getItem("tempId");
$("body").$('div#'+tempId).addClass('activeFeaturedNews');
```

Comment: Are you able to get the value of stored item in next page?

Comment: I alerted the getItemId variable and it shows NULL.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is without redirecting it to the next page how come you can addClass? During the click function, first redirect it to the second page. Then addClass as you did.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass the id as hash parameter in href e.g. `href="http://example.com/about#your-id"`

Now, on next page, you can get the hash using javascript i.e.

```
var curHash = window.location.hash;
$(""+curHash).addClass('activeFeaturedNews');
```